# Ситуация с Version code для Production/QA билдов

Tags: android

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться на практическом примере.
Есть production и staging сборки Android приложения. К примеру production сборка имеет versionName 1.0 и versionCode 1. При этом для релиза готова staging сборка с versionName 1.1 и versionCode 2 которая отдается QA на тестирование. В ситуации когда QA вернет баг репорт, а разработчики исправят их и вернут обратно в тестирование, versionName остается тот же самый, а versionCode должен быть увеличен на единицу? Т.е. быть 3 и увеличиваться до тех пор пока QA не одобрит релиз. Если versionCode увеличивается на еденицу, то например, в итоге в продакшене будут сборки 1.0 (1) и 1.1 (3). 
Является ли это правильным подходом?